# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in JavaScript when creating a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, el

I am using jsp and creating a JavaScript map the following way:

```
map = new Object();
<c:forEach items="${companyNames}" var="companyName">
  map[${companyName[1]}] = ${companyName[0]};
</c:forEach>
```

However I keep on getting the following error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
map = new Object();
map[Citigroup] = 1;
map[HSBC] = 2;
map[Credit Suisse] = 3;
```

When I go on the Chrome console and see the error source I see a red line under Suisse, what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wrap your keys in quotation marks.

Something like:

```
    map = new Object();
   <c:forEach items="${companyNames}" var="companyName">
      map["${companyName[1]}"] = ${companyName[0]};
  </c:forEach>
```

My syntax above may not be 100% correct but essentially you want:

```
map["Credit Suisse"] = 3;
```